# Interfacing Gtk with Mono on Linux

Tags: python, linux, mono, gtk, gtk#

I've got a Raspberry Pi-like device running Linux, connected to a custom printer. There is also an LCD touch screen that the user utilizes to interact with the printer (select files, configure the printer, print, etc.).

The printer controller was written in C#, so we run Mono on top of the Linux kernel to handle the printer.

The LCD screen is written in Gtk#, since we want to use Gtk as the UI layer of choice, and so it interfaces with our C# code. The problem is that Gtk# bindings only go up to [2.12](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php), and there are features we need from 2.14 and later (or even 3.x).

Since the device is running Linux, is there a way to use a C++ or Python- based binding for Gtk, and then pass signals between that and C#? I would need input from the printer (like printing status) to be sent to the Gtk handling the screen, and inputs from the screen (like "print the selected file") to be sent from Gtk back to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

Run a systemwide (or user) dbus daemon. Interconnect via dbus – [gdbus (just a server example](https://github.com/bratsche/glib/blob/master/gio/tests/gdbus-example-server.c) and [dbus-sharp](https://github.com/mono/dbus-sharp).

I'd suggest you to go for either C or python with the gobject introspection (not the wrapper stuff!) as they are usually better maintained than gtkmm (which "just" wraps gtk+ into class structures).